# How to expand Visual Studio variables in the add-in code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

I'm working on a VS add-in. How do I expand variables like `$(ProjectDir)`?

Comment: are you trying to enumerate `$(ProjectDir)`?

Comment: @WasifHossain: No. I want to be able to expand any valid Visual Studio variable.

Comment: I am not clear what do you actually mean by "expanding"? is it expanding from UI or from code? sorry for my shortings.

Comment: @WasifHossain: from code, of course. I'm talking about writing an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something similar to what an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1408820/1810429) to a related question on SO describes.

The linked answer speaks to VC++ projects and `VCProject` etcetera; but a quick search yielded the [`VSProject` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/vslangproj.vsproject%28v=vs.120%29.aspx), which seems to provide a starting point for something similar with C#/VB.NET projects.

Specifically check out the [`VSProject.Project` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/vslangproj.vsproject.project.aspx) and the [`Project.ConfigurationManager` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.project.configurationmanager.aspx) to which the [`VSProject` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/vslangproj.vsproject%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) page directly and indirectly links.